# I am trying to save the form data. My Django form data is not saved, why?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to save form data from Django template to Django Model. Its not throwing any error but its not saving the data as well

Could you please let me know what could be the problem and how should I solve?

Here is my Django form template:

```
<form  method="POST" class="review-form" autocomplete="on">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <div class="rating-form">
      <label for="rating">Your Overall  Rating Of This Product :</label>
      <span class="rating-stars">
      <a class="star-1" href="#">1</a>
      <a class="star-2" href="#">2</a>
      <a class="star-3" href="#">3</a>
      </span>
      <select name="rating" id="rating" required=""
         style="display: none;">
         <option value="">Rate…</option>
         <option value="3">Average</option>
         <option value="2">Not that bad</option>
         <option value="1">Very poor</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <textarea cols="30" rows="6"
      placeholder="What did you like or dislike? What did you use this product for?" class="form-control"
      id="review" name="description"></textarea>
   <div class="row gutter-md">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <input type="text" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Your Name - This is how you'll appear to other customers*" id="author"  name ="name">
      </div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Submit Review</button>
</form>
```

My Forms.py

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Reviews
    fields = ('rating', 'description', 'display_name')
```

My Views:

```
def reviews(request, slug):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            form = ReviewForm(request.POST)                 
            if form.is_valid():
                review = form.save(commit=False)
                review.product = Products.objects.get(slug=slug)
                review.user = request.user
                review.display_name = request.name
                review.description = request.description
                review.rating = request.rating
                print(review)
                review.save()
                messages.success(request, "Review saved, Thank you for the feedback.")
                return redirect('products:products')                                
            else:          
                messages.error(request, 'Sorry! Only customer purchased this Item are eligible for the review')
        else: 
            pass   
    return redirect('ecommerce:products')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [generic ClassBasedViews](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-based-generic-views-django-create-retrieve-update-delete/#:%7E:text=Class%20Based%20Generic%20Views%20are,POST%20requests%20for%20a%20view.). It's worth it to learn the concept! You will have to write less code and you will be able to edit a model instance and delete it from the front end.